# Can I use The latest Vuetify version in the Html file?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuetify.js

My old project uses a normal HTML CSS JS file and I want to use Vuetify in HTML file but it doesn't work in the latest version.

So, I tried to use version 1.x and it working

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">



</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <v-app>
            <v-content>
                <v-container>Hello world
                    <v-btn color="success">success</v-btn>
                </v-container>
            </v-content>
        </v-app>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>


    <script>
        new Vue({ el: '#app' })
    </script>
</body>
```

But, if I tried version 2.x it not working

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@3.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <v-app>
            <v-content>
                <v-container>Hello world
                    <v-btn color="error">Error</v-btn>
                </v-container>
            </v-content>
        </v-app>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Can anyone explain it to me why The latest Vuetify version not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [Vuetify document](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start/#cdn-usage) you need to bootstrapping vuetify like this:

```
new Vue({ 
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify()
})
```

Now you can check its works:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@3.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <v-app>
            <v-content>
                <v-container>Hello world
                    <v-btn color="error">Error</v-btn>
                </v-container>
            </v-content>
        </v-app>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
</body>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        vuetify: new Vuetify()
    })
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Mohsen, Thanks for ur reply and help.